# Div is 100%width, but the browser still scrolls to the right

Tags: html, css

I am using October CMS for a project, but unfortunatley I am having problems. For one of my divs I have the background set to 100% width, however I am getting this problem where the div below it is smaller in width and the browser is scrolling to the right hand side? Anyone have any suggestions, I have tried everything?

Comment: please provide with some code.
both html and css

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `body` to be `max-width: 100%;` and `overflow-x: hidden;` so it doesn't allow user to scroll to the sides.

result:

```
body {
   max-width: 100%;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   ..
}
```

Comment: Worked a treat, I was missing the overflow:hidden! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code or example I cant really comment apart from saying saying try these two

```
box-sizing: border-box;

overflow-x: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think of is that you have another element that is wider than that div.... without a fiddle it is very hard to understand what the issue is.